# Bind single datagrid with two diff datasources (Stored Procedure output and ArrayList)

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have one datagrid and I want to show three column using it.
I have used stored procedure to show some records into datagrid.

stored procedure is :

```
procedure [dbo].[allKeys]
AS 
select id,key,username from keys_TB
```

the key in this procedure is encrypted so, need to convert it i have done that conversion and have keep those key is ArrayList.

But problem is have bind the remaining id,username columns to datagrid, unable to bind ArrayList to datagrid.

Code behind :

```
DataSet ds = clsBusinessLogic.allKeys();
dgrv_allkey.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
dgrv_allkey.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
dgrv_allkey.Columns["id"].DataPropertyName = "id";
DataGridViewColumn id = dgrv_allkey.Columns[0];
this.dgrv_allkey.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
id.Width = 60;

dgrv_allkey.Columns["username"].DataPropertyName = "username";
DataGridViewColumn Custname = dgrv_allkey.Columns[2];
Custname.Width = 199;
this.dgrv_allkey.Columns[2].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
```

this is how i have bind id and username to datagrid but don't have any clue about key.

and i have called the stored procedure [allKeys] through clsBusinessLogic.allKeys() method

Comment: Don't ever use `ArrayList`. It has been obsolete for over a decade.

Comment: @JohnSaunders please suggest another solution ...

Answer (score 0):

First add an databinding complete event to the grid:

```
dgrv_allkey.DataBindingComplete += dgrv_allkey_DataBindingComplete;
```

Then add the result set of stored procedure as the grid datasoruce:

```
dgrv_allkey.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
dgrv_allkey.Columns["id"].DataPropertyName = "id";
////and other formating what ever needed.
```

Due to setting the datasource the event will be fired, and then in this event change the value of the key cell for each row.

```
private void dgrv_allkey_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    // Change Column Value for the DataGridView. 
    foreach (DataGridViewColumn i in dataGridView1.Columns)
    {
        if (i.Name == "key")
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                string oldvalue = row.Cells["key"].Value as string;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(oldvalue))
                {
                    // perform decoding here and set the decoded value here..
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: am unable to get the string from that datagrid to convert... actually "oldvalue = row.Cells["key"].Value as string;" returns null.../. don't now why

Comment: Can you check in watch, what data table column names are ?

Comment: everything is right .. but when trying get value from datagrid code returns null

Comment: gridview1.rows shows exact no of values, now it shows 5 rows.. and row.Cells  gives index for particular row..